# Calling a method when it finds results

Tags: c#, methods, static-methods

I have the following method `DWCompare` and I created a method `ErrorsDiscovered` to check if the method below is true.  How do I avoid the error in the 2nd method?

> Error: Can't convert method group 'DWCompare' to non-delegate type bool.

```
public static void DWCompare()
{
    var performDataHour = DbCall.PerformanceDatas.Where(d => 
        d.loggedAt > hourlyBegin && d.loggedAt < hourlyEnd).ToList();

    var performanceDataOneDay = DbCall.PerformanceDatas.Where(o => 
        o.loggedAt >= dayBegin && o.loggedAt < dayEnd).ToList();

    var UniqueFunctionCallsThisHour = performDataHour.GroupBy(g => g.functionName)
        .ToLookup(g => g.First().functionName, g => g.Average(gx => gx.functionTime))
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.FirstOrDefault()).Take(5);

    var UniqueFunctionCallsDay = performanceDataOneDay.ToLookup(g => g.functionName);

    performEmailDisplay += "<table>";
    performEmailDisplay += "<tr>";
    performEmailDisplay += "<td><b>Function</b></td>";
    performEmailDisplay += "<td><b>Hourly Average</b></td>";
    performEmailDisplay += "<td><b>Daily Average</b></td>";
    performEmailDisplay += "</tr>";

    foreach (var function in UniqueFunctionCallsThisHour)
    {
        var key = function.Key;
        var HourlyAverage = function.First();
        var DailyAverageData = UniqueFunctionCallsDay[key];
        double DailyAverage;

        if (DailyAverageData != null && DailyAverageData.Count() > 0)
        {
            DailyAverage = DailyAverageData.Average(f => f.functionTime);

            if (HourlyAverage > DailyAverage + DailyAverageData.Select(x => 
                x.functionTime).ToList().StandardDeviation())
            {
                performEmailDisplay += "<tr>";
                performEmailDisplay += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
                performEmailDisplay += "<td>" + HourlyAverage + "</td>";
                performEmailDisplay += "<td>" + DailyAverage + "</td>";
                performEmailDisplay += "</tr>";
            }                     
        }
    }

    performEmailDisplay += "</table>";
}

public static void ErrorsDiscovered()
{
    if (DWCompare)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DWCompare` method doesn't return anything, so it's hard to tell how you want to determine if it's "true".

Comment: @Amy I do not want DWCompare to return anything.  I only want an email sent when that method finds when functions slow.

Comment: If you don't want `DWCompare` to return anything, then what do you expect `if (DWCompare)` to evaluate? `if` conditions must return a `bool`...

Comment: @Rufus L - how would I change the logic without interrupting the intent of the method?

Comment: Remove the `if` and just call `DWCompare();` followed by `SendEmail();`? If that doesn't work, please describe more specifically what you mean by *"without interrupting the intent of the method"* From what I can tell, `DWCompare` adds an html table to a private field called `performEmailDisplay`. If there's something that happens in that method that you want to use to determine if you should call `SendEmail()`, then modify the method to return a `bool` and return true or false based on that "something".

Comment: @Rufud L  these are my last methods.  Does this cause an email to be sent only if there is data found in DWCompare()?

Comment: You said _"I created a method .. to check if the method below is true"_ and then said _"I do not want DWCompare to return anything"_. These two don't mix!

Comment: public static void ErrorsDiscovered()
        {
            DWCompare();
            GatherErrorData();
            SendEmail();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            
            ErrorsDiscovered();
            Console.WriteLine("Program Complete");
        }

Comment: Hi @AhmedAbdelhameed.  I want an email to be sent if another method finds slower run-times from a database.

Comment: @RufusL I am putting results into a table that is being put into an email.  I want the code to check for errors, but I do not want the checking to stop by having the method return something.

Comment: Then your method that looks for slower run times should return a bool, something like `public static bool SlowerRuntimesExist()`. Then your function could look like: `if (SlowerRuntimesExist()) SendEmail;`

Comment: What do you mean by *"I do not want the checking to stop by having the method return something"*? You can just return `true` or `false` at the end, after you're done with all the checking.

Comment: @Pens_Cup87 _"I want an email to be sent if another method finds **XXXX**"_ Do as Rufus told you from the beginning. Change your `DWCompare` method into a method that returns `bool` (i.e., `public static bool DWCompare`) and within your method check for the "**XXXX**", then return either true or false based on that.

Comment: @RufusL does the bool return type require a return value?

Comment: The confusing thing to me is that I don't see anywhere in `DWCompare` where you do any checking for errors.

Comment: @RufusL I have other method for getting the error information.

Comment: It sounds like you've written methods without first designing your program. I think some time spent putting all your logic into a flow chart will really help clear up what methods you need to write and how they interact with each other.

Comment: @RufusL This console app has been getting more detail as I have progressed.  The end goal is to have an alert email sent when run times exceed 2 standard deviations.  The math is done, but I want to get the app to only send emails when there are slow functions verses sending an email every day or hour.

Comment: It might be helpful if you upload an image of the section of your flowchart around the `ErrorsDiscovered()` method, because as it stands that method is a mystery, both in it's signature and it's content.

Comment: @RufusL The only part of the method I did not copy/paste were variables.  There was not a flow chart for this app.  These are the variables: DateTime hourlyBegin = new DateTime(2018, 3, 13, 12, 0, 0);
            DateTime hourlyEnd = hourlyBegin.AddHours(1);
            DateTime dayBegin = new DateTime(2018, 3, 7);
            DateTime dayEnd = new DateTime(2018, 3, 8);

Comment: In general, you should create a flow diagram, at least a high level one, before you start writing your code. Knowing the full flow in your mind beforehand saves lots of time later. If you don't do it then, then the next best time to do it is when your own code is confusing you (or won't work the way you want it to). If you spent the last 30 minutes creating your logic workflow / decision tree, you would probably already have your answer! :)

Comment: There was an initial discussion, but I am a new dev and was focusing on the pieces more than how everything fits together.

I changed the return type to bool.  If I end the method with "return true", will that always cause an email to be sent?

Comment: If the method always returns true, then anything that depends on its return value will always behave the same.

Answer (score -2):

Use try catch block so sendEmail() will not be called in case of error, catch block will be executed
    public static void ErrorsDiscovered() { 
    try
    {
        DWCompare();
        SendEmail();
    }
    catch
    {
        // handle error
    }